# I have a question about setting up the microphone

Tags: raspbian

```
pcm.!default{
type asym
playback.pcm{
type hw
card 0
}
capture.pcm{
type plug
slave.pcm “hw:1, 0”
} 
}
ctl.!default{
 type hw
card 0  
}
```

Can you interpret each coding language?

I'm asking you a question because it's my first time coding.
example : `pcm.!default` >> Initial value of output

Comment: Hi @김현제, Welcome! Ah let me see. I guess your code is using PCM (Pulse Code Modulation) protocol to input audio signal from sound card 0, input channel and output asynchronously to same card's output channel. Just now I google searched your code segment and got two billion results from my samsung galaxy. I would appreciate it if you can give me a galaxy link to narrow down my search.

Comment: type asym << What is the meaning of this?

Comment: Ah not sure.  Let me google.  26 Million Resutls. 約 26,200,000 項搜尋結果 (0.36 秒). I would appreciate it if you can give me a galaxy link to narrow down my search.

Comment: I googled your "type asym" code segment and found 約 5,800,000 項搜尋結果 (0.32 秒) . I still need your samsung link to narrow down my wild/wide guesses.  And I forgot to beg your pardon:  My IQ is only 97! :(

Comment: You asked: "*Can you interpret each coding language?*" but what is the problem?